# Shell Script to look for all lines in a file having '500' in the 11 column taking too long to run

Tags: ubuntu, shell, shell-script, awk

I wrote the following script as a practice :

```
#!/bin/bash

MyFile=$1

while read p; do

error=$(echo $p | awk '{print $11}')

        if [ "$error" = "500" ]
        then
                echo $p
        fi

done < $MyFile
```

The problem is that the script runs slowly taking hours to complete, my setup :

- Ubuntu on Windows 10 (64 with intel i7 6400 2.80GHz and 8G Ram).

Is there an issue with my setup or with the logic of the script ?
Thanks,

Comment: I don't really get what you're trying to do or how it's supposed to work but is there any reason `grep` is insufficient? What size does the input log file have?

Comment: Grep is sufficient (grep " 500 " does the trick) i'm just experimenting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$(` runs a subshell, so does the pipe `|`. It's better to do all the work in one shell or one language.

E.g. do all the work in awk:

```
awk '($11==500){print}' "$1"
```

Or without shelling out:

```
while read -a columns ; do
    [[ ${columns[10]} == 500 ]] && echo "${columns[@]}"
done < "$1"
```